# How to get the list of contributors and their level of participation?

Tags: mediawiki

I am creating a site under mediawiki. Is there a feature or an extension to know for a version which users have contributed to this version and in what proportion? For example, for the article on [new-york in wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York), know the list of contributors of this version and in what proportion did they participate?

Answer (score 0):

`prop=contributors`. See the [contributors API doc page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Contributors) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mainly seems to be about Wikipedia, which has a tool for this:

https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo

For your specific example, the link is:

https://xtools.wmflabs.org/articleinfo/fr.wikipedia.org/New%20York

The tool, XTools, is open source and may be useful for other MediaWiki installations as well:

https://github.com/x-tools/xtools